# Size of the Kafka Streams In Memory Store

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am doing an aggregation on a Kafka topic stream and saving to an in memory state store. I would like to know the exact size of the accumulated in memory data, is this possible to find?

I looked through the jmx metrics on jconsole and Confluent Control Centre but nothing seemed relevant, is there anything I can use to find this out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number of stored key-value-pairs of an in-memory store, via `KeyValueStore#approximateNumEntries()` (for the default in-memory-store implementation, this number is actually accurate). If you can estimate the byte size per key-value pair, you can do the math.

However, estimating the byte size of an object is pretty hard to do in general in Java. The problem is, that Java does not provide any way to receive the actual size of an object. Also, objects can be nested making it even harder. Finally, besides the actual data, there is always some metadata overhead per object, and this overhead is JVM implementation dependent.

Comment: Thanks I was wondering if I had to do it that way, do you know if the Persisted Store size is accessible and would be the comparable byte size to the in memory size?

Comment: I also noticed that the method approximateNumEntries()  did not update for quite a while when sending a large amount of Tombstoned messages to the stream, for example the count returned 100,000 but could not query any key, so they were removed correctly.

Comment: It it the same for persisted store. The default uses RocksDB and does only approximate the number of keys/value pairs though... For the second question: maybe it's related to caching... if the cache is not flushed, the store might still report the old value. Can you try disabling caching?